# UITableViewController with Section and Parse as BackEnd server

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I don't find any good and update answers about loading data from Parse to an UITableViewController with sections.

I know that using PFQueryTableViewController is only possible for 1 section.

I have a class Recipes with the following columns in Parse:
Section; Name; Calories

Hence my database looks like this
Morning; Eggs; 120
Morning, Bacon; 250
Lunch; Meat; 340
....

I compute a function to query the data from Parse like this:

```
func queryData(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: self.recipesClass as String)
    //query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Results were successfully found, looking first on the
            // network and then on disk.
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.tableSections.addObject(object)
            }

        } else {
            // The network was inaccessible and we have no cached data for
            // this query.
        }
    }
}
```

Where tableSections is a NSMutableArray.

From here, I'm a bit lost on how to proceed to achieve the required results.

Please help,

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you like the sections on the UITableView to match the sections on the Parse.com table? Also, how familiar are you with `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes! The section's names from Parse.com must match with the sections of UITableView.
I'm a beginner but I have the basics on UITableView concept

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create different sections based on the 'Section' property of each returned object. This is a bit tricky for someone new to `UITableView`, but it can be accomplished in around an hour with Sensible TableViews (http://sensiblecocoa.com/).

Sensible TableViews will let you take an array of objects and separate it into several sections. It even interfaces directly with Parse.com if you so desire. I use it in almost all of my apps for its simple, clean approach to tables and cloud data.

Start with their online guide here:
http://sensiblecocoa.com/usermanual/latest/

You can also skip right to Parse.com Integration here: http://sensiblecocoa.com/usermanual/latest/#ExploringParseComBinding

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate this but in a first lecture it doesn't treat the multiple section aspect.

Is there another way than using Sensitive TableViews ? It doesn't seems to be free to use Parse.com Binding.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe it should be better to create a class Recipes : PFObject, PFSubclassing and define attributes inside no ?

Comment: Agreed- I would use the PFObject subclassing as opposed to key-value coding via `objectForKey:` calls.

Comment: I didn't achieve it yet :(

For now I have an array of dictionnaries where each cell of this array is a PFObject transform to a NSMutableDictionnary (Section, Name, Calories)

I don't know how to display it by section. 

Any ideas guys ? Please

Comment: Did you end up using sensible cocoa or the native UITableView delegates? Open a new question and I'll help you solve the sections separation issue :-)